# Google Maps Searchbox Positioning (library angular-google-maps)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps

I try to position the Google Maps searchbox variable. A list shows all markers and under those markers there should be the searchbox. As the list grows the searchbox moves down. I use this library: [Angular Google Maps](http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/)
There is a directive called `<ui-gmap-search-box>`. But it must be inside `<div id="map_canvas"> </div>` and the list is outside of that `div`.

Comment: Post some code of yours, and explain what are you having issues with exactly.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the custom control functions provided by the Google Maps API.

You can position your controls on the top left corner of your maps, and create click event listeners for your control and do your work from there.

Refer to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls#CustomControls) for more information on Custom Controls.

Also, I made some quick changes to [this sample](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/control-custom), and made this example here. Hope it helps.

```js
var map;
//var chicago = new google.maps.LatLng(41.85, -87.65);

/**
 * The CenterControl adds a control to the map that recenters the map on Chicago.
 * This constructor takes the control DIV as an argument.
 * @constructor
 */
controlUIs = [];

function CenterControl(controlDiv, map) {


  locations = [new google.maps.LatLng(37.7833, -122.4167),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.3382, -121.8863),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.4223662, -122.0839445),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.8694772, -122.2577238),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.7919615, -122.2287941),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.6256441, -122.0413544)
  ];
  for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    // Set CSS for the control border
    var controlUI = document.createElement('div');
    controlUI.style.backgroundColor = '#fff';
    controlUI.style.border = '2px solid #fff';
    controlUI.style.borderRadius = '3px';
    controlUI.style.boxShadow = '0 2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.3)';
    controlUI.style.cursor = 'pointer';
    controlUI.style.marginBottom = '22px';
    controlUI.style.textAlign = 'center';
    controlUI.title = 'Click to recenter the map';
    controlUIs[i] = controlUI;
    controlDiv.appendChild(controlUIs[i]);

    // Set CSS for the control interior
    var controlText = document.createElement('div');
    controlText.style.color = 'rgb(25,25,25)';
    controlText.style.fontFamily = 'Roboto,Arial,sans-serif';
    controlText.style.fontSize = '16px';
    controlText.style.lineHeight = '38px';
    controlText.style.paddingLeft = '5px';
    controlText.style.paddingRight = '5px';
    controlText.innerHTML = 'Location ' + i;
    controlText.location = locations[i];
    controlUIs[i].appendChild(controlText);


    // Setup the click event listeners: simply set the map to
    // Chicago
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(controlUIs[i], 'click', function(click) {
      map.setCenter(click.target.location)
    });
  }

}

function initialize() {
  var mapDiv = document.getElementById('map-canvas');
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 10,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.6326196, -122.1568744)

  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, mapOptions);

  // Create the DIV to hold the control and
  // call the CenterControl() constructor passing
  // in this DIV.
  var centerControlDiv = document.createElement('div');
  var centerControl = new CenterControl(centerControlDiv, map);

  centerControlDiv.index = 1;
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(centerControlDiv);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
      html,
      body,
      #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true"></script>

<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the Google Maps API Search box instead of the library's search box.

main.js:

```
var searchBox = function() {
  var input = document.getElementById('autocomplete');

  var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);

    google.maps.event.addListener(searchBox, 'places_changed', function() {
  });

}; // end searchBox
```

The function searchBox() is executed in `$scope.init()`.

index.html:

`<input id="autocomplete" ng-model="newPlace" type="text">`